# Input filter on differential amplifier input

Tags: amplifier, filter, differential, input

[image: DC level filter]

Hi, I need to determine the transfer function Vout/Vin. A traditional differential amplifier transfer function without the 2.2uF on the input side would be G1 = (Z2/Z1)*Vin, where Z2 = (2.2uF // 150kOhms) and Z1 = 450kOhms + 150kOhms . I am having some trouble to model de 2.2uF input capacitor. The output filter stage (Rout = 10k and Cout = 2.2uF) transfer function is G2 = 1/(sRC+1). The total transfer function without the input capacitor is G1*G2. How do I deal with the input capacitor filter stage (2.2uF connecting both inputs after the 450k resistor)?

EDIT:
[image]

I believe this is the correct transfer function for the input filter, it gives the 1/4 gain with some low pass dynamics Vout/Vin = G(s) = (1/4)*2.02/(s + 2.02)

Second stage considering only the op amp ( (2.2uF//150kOhms)/(150kOhms) ratio ): G1(s) = 3.03/(s + 3.03)

Output stage considering the RC filter: G2 = 1/(sRC+1) = 45.45/(s + 45.45)

Answer (score 1):

It is still a function of impedance ratios but a passive LPF loaded by an active filter raises the breakpoint and also attenuates to 1/4 or -12dB at DC with these 4:1 R ratios.

-3dB BW 242 mHz, ...  469mHz  without C1

DC gain -12 dB   ........ same
2 Hz -40dB ............  -24 dB
2kHz -80dB  ............ -44 dB
-40 dB/dec  ............  -20dB/dec

What do you really want? 2nd order filter with 0dB DC gain at 0.33 Hz[?](http://www.falstad.com/afilter/circuitjs.html?cct=$%203%200.000005%205%2050%205%2050%0A%25%200%20832553.2074018733%0Ac%20232%20144%20232%20168%200%205.499999999999999e-10%200%0Ar%20344%20200%20296%20200%200%20600000%0Ar%20184%20144%20136%20144%200%20150000%0Ag%20232%20168%20232%20184%200%0Ac%20296%20232%20344%20232%200%205.5e-10%200%0Aw%20184%20144%20232%20144%200%0AO%20392%20152%20440%20152%200%0A170%2096%20112%2064%20112%202%2020%204000%205%200.1%0Aa%20296%20152%20344%20152%203%2015%20-15%201000000%0Aw%20296%20160%20296%20200%200%0Aw%20184%20200%20296%20200%200%0Aw%20296%20144%20232%20144%200%0Aw%20344%20232%20344%20200%200%0Aw%20344%20200%20344%20152%200%0Ar%2096%20112%2096%20144%200%20150000%0Ac%2096%20144%2096%20200%200%202.2e-9%200%0Ar%2096%20200%2096%20232%200%20150000%0Ag%2096%20232%2096%20248%200%0Aw%2096%20144%20136%20144%200%0Aw%2096%20200%20136%20200%200%0Ar%20184%20200%20136%20200%200%20150000%0Aw%20296%20232%20296%20200%200%0Ar%20392%20152%20344%20152%200%2010000%0Ar%20184%20168%20184%20144%200%20150000%0Aw%20184%20168%20232%20168%200%0Ac%20392%20152%20392%20208%200%202.2e-9%200%0Ag%20392%20208%20392%20224%200%0A)

Comment: Hint : my “?” Has a sim for improved design , maybe but may want to answer me.

Comment: Hi Tony thanks for your answer, I would like to know how to obtain the transfer function equation when I have this kind of input filter on the op amp. I got the frequency response running anac sweep on the circuit but I would like to know how to obtain the equations. I need this transfer function because I will design a control loop for a variable that is measured by this circuit (already implemented on hardware).

Comment: What phase margin and slew rate is needed?

Comment: You have to short the Op Amp inputs to get the voltage on C1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I believe I got the correct transfer functions (I edited the post including the answers I got.). This circuit is being used to extract the DC value from an AC voltage (127Vrms/60Hz). I tuned a PI control loop to render a phase margin of 60 degrees and cutoff frequency of 0.3Hz to eliminate the DC value from a power inverter (LC filter drived by a half-bridge).

Comment: That's good enough for 85 dB of attenuation @ 60 Hz but a relatively slow loop for preventing saturation but I guess good enough.  A faster response might be with a 2 stage notch filter + LPF